# Having issues with AVCaptureVideoOrientation showing camera preview incorrectly

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, rotation

I've been given some code from 2011 to update for a client, I've managed to get it all sorted for iOS7 etc and submitted the update to Apple.

I now have an issue with the app which I need to sort out as soon as possible. I'm really struggling to find a solution, I've tried all sorts!

In brief, this app allows users to take multiple photos in a custom camera view (with a camera preview at all times) then hit a done button to close the window and return to the previous screen.

However, when the camera preview shows on screen, it's is in the incorrect orientation, by 90 degrees counter clockwise.

Here is an example.....

[image: Photo example of camera issue]

I need to force the user to take the photo in landscape mode.

The second issue is if the user does take a landscape photo, it saves it 90 degrees counter clockwise as well.

Can anybody help????

Full code is below, this is using the original code that was supplied, witha  few tweaks to try and fix it without much joy!

Many thanks in advance

Simon

```
//
//  CameraViewController.m
//  X
//
//  Created by X on 8/9/11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "CameraViewController.h"
#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>




static AVCaptureVideoOrientation avOrientationForInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation iOrientation);

static AVCaptureVideoOrientation avOrientationForInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation iOrientation)
{
    AVCaptureVideoOrientation result = iOrientation;
    if ( iOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft )
        result = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    else if ( iOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight )
        result = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
    return result;
}





@implementation CameraViewController
@synthesize stillImageOutput, delegate;
@synthesize session, captureVideoPreviewLayer;


- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    AVCaptureVideoOrientation avcaptureOrientation = avOrientationForInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation);
    self.captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation =  avcaptureOrientation;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [stillImageOutput release];
    [captureVideoPreviewLayer release];
    [session release];

    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    // rotate the status bar
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;

    // try and rotate the camera live preview


}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

    self.captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
    AVCaptureVideoOrientation avcaptureOrientation = avOrientationForInterfaceOrientation(self.interfaceOrientation);
    self.captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation =  avcaptureOrientation;
    //captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    NSLog(@"doing something");
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = cameraView.bounds;


    [cameraView.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
    if (!input) {
        // Handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
    }
    [session addInput:input];

    stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
    [stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

    [session addOutput:stillImageOutput];

    [session startRunning];

    canDismiss = 0;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}


// Set the camera to force itself to a landscape view
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}


/*- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 // Return YES for supported orientations
 //return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) | (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) | (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
 }*/

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    }

    // and so on for other orientations
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft));
}




- (void) didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    if ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]) ) {
        [topView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 27)];
        [bottomView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 453, 320, 27)];
    } else {
        [topView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 110)];
        [bottomView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 350, 320, 110)];
    }

    switch ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            btnDone.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3*M_PI_2);
            btnTakePicture.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3*M_PI_2);
            break;
        default:
            btnDone.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
            btnTakePicture.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
            break;
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(IBAction)takePhoto {
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections)
    {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts])
        {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
            {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection) { break; }
    }

    NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", stillImageOutput);
    canDismiss++;
    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
     {
         CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment( imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
         if (exifAttachments)
         {
             // Do something with the attachments.
             NSLog(@"attachements: %@", exifAttachments);
         }
         else
             NSLog(@"no attachments");

         int width = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"image_width"] intValue];
         int height = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"image_height"] intValue];

         NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
         UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
         NSLog(@"Image w:%f h:%f", image.size.width, image.size.height);
         UIImage * rotatedimage;
         if ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]) ) {

             // Rotate the image
             CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.height, image.size.width);
             CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
             CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate (NULL, newSize.width, newSize.height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
             CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
             if ( [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ) {
                 CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, newSize.height);
                 transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);

                 CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, -1.0, 1.0);
                 CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -newSize.width, 0);
                 CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
             }
             CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height), image.CGImage);
             CGImageRef sourceImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
             rotatedimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:sourceImageRef];
             CGContextRelease(ctx);

             NSLog(@"Rotated Image w:%f h:%f", rotatedimage.size.width, rotatedimage.size.height);

             // Scale the image
             newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
             UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
             [rotatedimage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
             //image is the original UIImage
             UIImage * newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
             UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
             NSLog(@"New Image w:%f h:%f", newImage.size.width, newImage.size.height);
             [delegate tookPhoto:newImage];
         } else {
             // Scale the image
             CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, image.size.height/(image.size.width/width));
             UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
             [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
             UIImage * newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
             UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
             NSLog(@"New Image w:%f h:%f", newImage.size.width, newImage.size.height);

             // Chop out the middle
             CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
             CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate (NULL, width, height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
             CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
             if ( [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown ) {
                 CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, newImage.size.height);
                 transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);

                 CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, -1.0, 1.0);
                 CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -newImage.size.width, 0);
                 CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
                 CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, (newImage.size.height-height)/2, newImage.size.width, newImage.size.height), newImage.CGImage);
             } else {
                 CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, -(newImage.size.height-height)/2, newImage.size.width, newImage.size.height), newImage.CGImage);
             }
             CGImageRef sourceImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
             CGContextRelease(ctx);
             [delegate tookPhoto:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:sourceImageRef]];
         }
         [image release];

         canDismiss--;
     }];
}


// action when the 'tick' button is pressed
-(IBAction)done {
    if ( canDismiss == 0 ) {
        self.delegate = nil;

        // animate the camera view away
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        // swap the status bar back to the default portrait
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Have you tried this https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureConnection/supportsVideoOrientation and Use http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/UIImage-categories.zip for your final image to get it perfect.

Comment: The second link should help a bit with the 2nd issue of the saving of landscape photos. I had already looked at the Apple docs, but I can't get any of the snippets to do anything

Comment: @SimonHume, Have you find any solution on this? If yes, please add your answer.